# Run Configuration not working and getting java Null pointer exception after Starting Anypoint Studio

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mule4

I am trying to run Mule projects in Anypoint Studio.But after running Mule application I am getting java Null pointer exception and the run congiuration VM arguments are also missing when I open run Configuration Window.I am using Anypoint Studio 7.4.1.I have not tried any changes in the Studio.ini file

Answer (score 0):

So, Anypoint Studio is running, you can create your project and start it. Right?
Then issue is within project itself and Null Poinetr exception tells you where exactly.
Show your stack trace and we can tell you what is wrong.

As of JVM arguments - they are empty by default. Or they can contain some special values for JVM which actually have no influence to the app - they change behavior of JVM
[image]

If you need to pass some values to your app then use environment variables
[image]

More about Properties is here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Properties.html

Comment: tried updating anypoint studio but still can't select run in run config.Also when i try to select project to set VM arguments the column gets set to null

Comment: Something tells me ("the column gets set to nul") that you want to pass some values into the app. I had expanded my answer. Is it what you are looknig for?

Comment: Got it!!.I updated Anypoint Studio and Mule Runtime.Thanks anyways!!